# How do I get my ASP.Net MVC2 application to authenticate with the SQL Server using Sql Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I deployed an ASP.net MVC 2 application on my Windows Server 2008 IIS7 server and it bombs out reporting:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

I have SQL Server authentication enabled on the server and I have created a login for the database that I am trying to reach. I don't understand why the 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'
credential is being used. This must be the context in which the application is running (application pool). I assumed that the application would just use the credentials specified in the connectionstring. How can configure IIS7 and/or ASP.net to just login using the user and pass provided in the connection string specified within the web.config?

Thanks a ton.

I'm pretty sure the problem is at the SQL Server or with my IIS configuration. The application works from my development machine.

Connnection String :

> connectionString="Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=TestPortal;User Id=username;Password=password;"

Comment: Is it working in development environment?

Comment: If this problem is related to sql then your connection string is probably incorrect.  If you could add it to your question it would help (obviously removing sensitive id/password).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Entity Framework connection string has:

> Integrated Security=True;

This should be removed from both the asp.net membership provider connectionstring as well as from the entity framework's generated connectionstring.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string should look like this:

```
Data Source=SomeServerName;Initial Catalog=SomeDB;User Id=user;Password=pwd;
```

And SQL authentication [must be enabled](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLMixedMode.aspx) on the SQL Server.

Comment: The connection string is correct. I'm fairly certain the issue is at the sql server or with my IIS configuration. The application works in my development environment.

Comment: @Nick, is SQL Authentication enabled on your SQL Server? Are you able to connect to it with the username and password using for example SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out that Entity Framework has an additional connection string. That connection string had Integrated Security=True;